# line plot on bar chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

[image: I would like to plot the line right on each bar, but there is strange reason that the line is inside the bars]
[image: this is overview of dataset the numbers are the moving averages]

I would like to present the data visualisation which includes line chart and bar chart.
Could you guys tell me what kind of mistakes I have made?
I guess if it because the moving weighted average caused this issue?

```
rollmean_covid  <- covid_ts1  %>% filter(Nation == "England") %>% select(date, daily_pos_num) %>% 
    mutate(pos_num01 = rollmean(daily_pos_num, k = 3, fill = NA),
           pos_num02 = rollmean(daily_pos_num, k = 5, fill = NA),
           pos_num03 = rollmean(daily_pos_num, k = 7, fill = NA),
           pos_num04 = rollmean(daily_pos_num, k = 10, fill = NA),
           pos_num05 = rollmean(daily_pos_num, k = 14, fill = NA))

rollmean_covid_metric <- rollmean_covid %>% gather(metric, number, pos_num01:pos_num05)
rollmean_covid_metric %>% filter(metric == "pos_num01") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(date, number), col = "Blue") +
  geom_col(aes(date, number), fill = "orange", alpha = 0.7)
```

edited1: the dataset overview is provided bellow.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   date       daily_pos_num pos_num01 pos_num02 pos_num03 pos_num04 pos_num05
   <date>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2020-01-30             2    NA          NA      NA          NA      NA    
 2 2020-01-30             0     0.667      NA      NA          NA      NA    
 3 2020-01-31             0     0           0.4    NA          NA      NA    
 4 2020-01-31             0     0           0       0.286      NA      NA    
 5 2020-02-01             0     0           0       0           0.3    NA    
 6 2020-02-01             0     0           0       0.143       0.1    NA    
 7 2020-02-02             0     0           0.2     0.143       0.1     0.286
 8 2020-02-02             0     0.333       0.2     0.143       0.2     0.143
 9 2020-02-03             1     0.333       0.2     0.143       0.2     0.143
10 2020-02-03             0     0.333       0.2     0.286       0.2     0.143
```

Comment: Hi James. You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: @AllanCameron I expect the line is on the top of bar, but I fail to plot the line over the bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple observations for one date, and by default the `position = "stack"` for `geom_col` so that's why the bars are taller. You probably want `position = "identity"`, this should work:

```
rollmean_covid_metric %>% 
    filter(metric == "pos_num01") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, number)) + 
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    geom_col(position = "identity", fill = "orange", alpha = 0.7)
```

Edit to add: as @chemdork123 points out in the comments, if one date has multiple values this probably won't give desired results. In general, the best solution for these types of problems is to munge your data into the correct shape before piping it into a `ggplot` call.

Comment: This answer +1.  OP, your `filter()` command prior to plotting is giving you duplicate data.  Check the data preparation prior to the `ggplot` call.  Setting `position="identity"` will work to fix your plot, but you will still be plotting two copies of `geom_col` on top of one another.  If they are duplicates... no huge deal, you'll just have darker bars.  If they are *not* duplicates, your results will still look wrong.  Without the original dataset, it's difficult to see where you're going wrong going from `rollmean_covid` to `rollmean_covid_metric`, but the answer lies within there.

Comment: Thanks for your help@DiceboyT @chemdork123 , this not only justify my problem but also let me more understand the logics of ggplot2